# Testing free memory on Debian

Tags: memory, vps

On my Virtual Server running Debian, I have impression, that there is wrongly configured memory, even though my provider claims everything works correctly.

Even with 3GB of RAM, I keep running out of memory, even though top commands claims it still has enough memory.

Is there a way to test, that the free memory is actually usable? For instance, if I had 1,5 GB of memory, I would like to create a block of 1 GB and see that everything still works correctly.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which applications are you using? There must be a reason that you are running out of memory.

Try command free:

```
$ free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          3022       2973         48          0        235       1948
-/+ buffers/cache:        790       2232
Swap:         3907          0       3907
```

This will show you something like the above (that is a 3 GB machine of my own).

Always check the system log of your machine if you have memory issues.

```
# tail /var/log/syslog
```